# Drupal Page 'Comment Settings' and comments on page not appearing

Tags: php, drupal

I've been playing around with comments, making custom comment sections and sort of editing the module. I also added new database columns in the 'comments' table so I can have different sets of comments for different kinds of pages. Somewhere along the way, I think I screwed something up with the module there. Now, when I go to any page or article and edit, I don't have the 'Comment Settings' section in which I can enable comments. Similarly, the comments no longer appear on any pages.

What might have happened? How do I fix this?

Comment: Alter drupal core's table is not advisable until you don't know enough knowledge. If you are try to introduce new functionality based on your new column, then create separate table map comment-id against your column and do further with query of your new table.

Comment: Are you saying I should create an additional table that maps certain comments to specific nodes? I think that would work well, but I'm still unsure how I would show only those comments on the right pages without altering te module.

Comment: Also, I'm still unsure how I can revert the module to make everything show again. The first comment on [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69628/page-comment-settings-and-comments-on-page-not-appearing) question explains that I probably broke something. I tried replacing the comment module folder with the original one from a new Drupal core and deleting the columns I added to the comment table, but that didn't work. How do I revert my changes?

Answer (score 1):

To configure comment settings on a specific content type:

1. Navigate to the Content types administration page (Administer > Structure > Content     types or http://example.com/admin/structure/types).
2. Find the content type you want to enable and click the "Edit" link.
3. Scroll down and click the "Comment Settings" tab.
4. Here you can specify several different settings (some options will not appear until you've selected a certain setting).

---

Default comment setting for new content

The comment setting on future content of this type will default to:

```
Hidden: No comments are allowed, and past comments are hidden.
Closed: No comments are allowed, but any past comments remain visible.
Open: Any future content of this type is open to new comments.
```

Note: this setting is a default, and is not retroactive to existing content of the type.
Threading

When this option is enabled, comments are displayed in a threaded list (replies are indented to make discussions easier to follow).
Comments per page

Specifies the maximum number of comments displayed on one page (additional pages will be added if you exceed this limit).
Allow comment title

When this option is enabled, a user can fill in a title for their comment (the title is optional).
Show reply form on the same page as comments

When this option is enabled, the reply form is displayed on the same page as the comments. (If this is not selected, clicking "Reply" will take you to a new page where you can fill in the reply form.)
Preview comments

You can specify whether a preview is "Required" (always be displayed prior to saving the comment), "Disabled" (never displayed), or "Optional" (the user has the option of displaying a preview).

Note: Be sure to click "Save content type" after configuring the settings.

Comment: I was trying to change that for a long time, and the most obvious settings that would allow comments were not working. I tried different settings and still couldn't get anything to show again. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/lE09fjA.png)'s a quick image of what I have set now, maybe I'm overlooking something.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info you added, but the problem is that none of these settings are returning the comment settings to the content type and the comments still aren't showing up on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I assume that you have data in comment table and you don't want loose your data. Before do following steps, Just take backup your db so that if anything goes wrong you can get backup. And take comment table as separate backup without problematic column.

```
Step1: Go to module and disable comment module.
Step2: Now uninstall comment module which is in uninstall tab. Now go to db and confirm comment table is deleted. If it is not delete, drop table manually.
Step3: Delete comment folder from core module's folder. 
Step4: Copy fresh comment folder. 
Step5: Now go to module page and enable comment module.
Step6: To debug just create any page and add comment and then verify.
Step7: If it is working, Then drop comment table and restore if from table backup.
Step8: Repeat step6 and verify.
```

**Note: It's not recommended in production environment. Please try to get some expert help if it is prod.**

**Note2: I have tried this in drupal 7.20**